# Inserting Char value to database column having DBCLOB 2g in DB2

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, rpgle

Logic 1:

```
Dcl-s WkoutJSON           Char(16000000);
```

This wkoutJSON field contains built JSON value

Then I am trying to insert to Database

```
Insert into TBLPOST(TBLPAYLD)
  Values(
    Method 1 // cast(:wkoutJSON as dbclob(2g) ccsid 1200)
    Method 2 // DBCLOB(:wkoutJSON, 1073741823, CODEUNITS32));
```

I have tried in two ways. both are not working getting wkoutJSON is not declared or not usable

Logic 2:

```
Dcl-s WkoutJSON           Char(16000000); 
Dcl-s DbClobVar           SQLTYPE(DBCLOB:8386550);
```

This wkoutJSON field contains built JSON value

```
DbClobVar_Data = %Trim(%Graph(wkoutJSON));
DbClobvar_Len  = %Len(DbClobVar_Data);
```

Then I am trying to insert to Database

```
Insert into TBLPOST(TBLPAYLD)
  Values(:DbClobvar);
```

Not working getting wkoutJSON is not declared or not usable

Kindly help me to insert the char values to dbclob.

Comment: A rpgle variable of type `char(n)` cannot be used by SQL if longer than 32766, see [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzajp/rzajpequivsqlirpg.htm). Maybe you can use [GET_DBCLOB_FROM_FILE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzscagetdbclobfile.htm) to load data and then a [LOB LOCATOR](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzajp/rzajpirpglobloc.htm) to manipulate it. Or directly use a [DB_CLOB file reference](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzajp/rzajpirpglobfileref.htm)

Comment: is it possible to convert char to graph, and move the converted graphical value to DBCLOB column field?

Comment: Yes you can `dcl-s xxx ucs2(16383) ccsid(1200)` then `xxx = WkoutJSON`, but If you use a `GRAPH` or `UCS2` variable, then it is limited to 16383 characters (32766 bytes) as a host variable. Sure you can loop over your original data and `VALUES :lob_locator = :lob_locator concat :xxx` and when done `insert ... :llob_locator`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Insert into TBLPOST(TBLPAYLD)
>   Values(
>     Method 1 // cast(:wkoutJSON as dbclob(2g) ccsid 1200)
>     Method 2 // DBCLOB(:wkoutJSON, 1073741823, CODEUNITS32));
> ```
>
> getting wkoutJSON is not declared or not usable

Both of these ways are trying to use `:wrkoutJSON` in the sql, because `wrkoutJAOS` is too large for embedded SQL. But you also said:

> Logic 2:
>
> ```
> Dcl-s WkoutJSON           Char(16000000); 
> Dcl-s DbClobVar           SQLTYPE(DBCLOB:8386550);
> ```
>
> This wkoutJSON field contains built JSON value
>
> ```
> DbClobVar_Data = %Trim(%Graph(wkoutJSON));
> DbClobvar_Len  = %Len(DbClobVar_Data);
> ```
>
> Then I am trying to insert to Database
>
> ```
> Insert into TBLPOST(TBLPAYLD)
>   Values(:DbClobvar);
> ```
>
> Not working getting wkoutJSON is not declared or not usable

This is puzzling because you are not using wrkoutJSON in the SQL, and this is actually almost the way to do what you want. But, DbClobvar_DATA is not a varchar, so trimming the data before loading it will not help. you really need:

```
DbClobVar_Data = %Graph(wkoutJSON);
DbClobvar_Len  = %Len(%trim(DbClobVar_Data));
```